# Kubuntu installation stuck at 48% downloading packages

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, kubuntu

This is 16.04.2. I'm installing on a new, clean PC (doesn't have anything installed). The installation was proceeding fine, including connection to WiFi, but at the middle of the installation, it got stuck and has been that way for the last hour. It's stuck at the "downloading packages" step, at 48%. The system is not frozen - I verified this by pressing Alt+Tab which did show the window switcher on the left.

**Any ideas?** Would it work better if I used a wired connection just for the installation? Note that I'm posting this from another PC connected to the same wireless network, so the problem doesn't seem to be in my WiFi network.

Comment: Try installing again, you may have just been unlucky.

Comment: And verify the integrity of your installation media using some sort of checksum.

Answer (score 0):

It turns the PC came with 2 antennas to be screwed into the back of the PC. Without them, WiFi access is really wonky - that was causing the problem.